# "No tests to run" with maven test goal

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I'm using maven version 3.5.2 and seemingly have correct dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.devtop</groupId>
    <artifactId>discount-calculator</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Testing dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However when I run `mvn clean test` it can't find any tests, and simply prints out:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ discount-calculator ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

My tests classes do end with word "Test" and are properly annotated, I can run them through intellij, but maven seems to have problems

One of the test classes I have in package residing in `<projectDir>/src/main/test`:

```
package com.devtop.discountcalculator.discount;

import com.devtop.discountcalculator.RuleReturnsTrue;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

public class RuleChainFactoryTest {

    @Test
    public void testChainRules_oneRule_exception() {
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> RuleChainFactory.getInstance().chainRules(new RuleReturnsTrue()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work when you omit the `spring-test` framework?

Comment: @Sormuras - nop

Comment: Can you Surefire `2.22.1` a shot? It does work with Jupiter `5.5.0-M1`, according to https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.5.0-M1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml

Comment: didnt work, even with junit-jupiter artifact instead of engine

Comment: Please show your test classes?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Maven favors convention over configuration, and has standard directory layout.
By default, it expects tests in src/test/java.

Check [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). The defaults are defined in [the super POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM).

The defaults can be overriden (if you have good reason to do so).

Comment: Do doublecheck the directories, as mentioned. The `test/` directory must be under `src/`, **NOT** under `src/main/` :) So: `src/main/java/com/example/thing/Hello.java` would have the test in the path: `src/test/java/com/example/thing/HelloTest.java`